# AngularJS IDirectiveLinkFn interface

Tags: angularjs, typescript, nuget-package

Examples for implementing the directive's `link` method in typescript use as the fourth parameter instance of `ng.INgModelController`

```
public link($scope: ng.IScope, el: JQuery, attrs: ng.IAttributes, ngModel: ng.INgModelController)
```

but this does not compile for me (I have the latest angularjs.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped 6.5.6 installed), because the interface `IDirectiveLinkFn` expects as the fourth parameter instance of `IController` and not `INgModelController`.

If the fourth parameter is modified to be of type `IController`, now it compiles, but the interfaces are very different. How is it possible after this change to access the model properties `ngModel.$viewValue` or `ngModel.$render` inside link function?

The packages.config contains these packages:

```
<package id="angularjs.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped" version="6.5.6" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="angular-material.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped" version="1.6.4" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="angular-ui.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped" version="2.4.3" targetFramework="net452" />
```

Comment: Does `ngModel: ng.INgController & ng.INgModelController` do the trick?

Comment: Thanks, yes, it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since [INgModelController](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/628cbd69e1213d8b3f83950e2034e790b37d206a/types/angular/index.d.ts#L382) doesn't extend [IController](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/628cbd69e1213d8b3f83950e2034e790b37d206a/types/angular/index.d.ts#L1862) and isn't compatible with it (this is an oversight in AngularJS typing), the solution is to use union type:

```
public link($scope: ng.IScope, el: JQuery, attrs: ng.IAttributes, 
  ngModel: ng.INgController & ng.INgModelController) {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have @types declarations installed ?
For example, in `"@types/angular": "^1.6.43"`, in `IController` type you will find the next options:

```
// IController implementations frequently do not implement any of its methods.
// A string indexer indicates to TypeScript not to issue a weak type error in this case.
[s: string]: any;
```

If I correct, this means you can use any of properties from the `IController` type.

Another option is to use a type coercion, something like this:

```
let viewValue = (ngModel as ng.INgModelController).$viewValue;
```

Comment: I use Visual Studio nuget angularjs.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped for type definition, will try the type coercion.